# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col_name'

Tags: python, pandas

I read a csv file using

```
x = pd.read_table('path to csv')
```

and I can see a row-wise comma-separated list of the data values on printing x which is fine. But when I try to access any column using x.col1, it gives an error :

```
**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col1'**
```

I also tried doing :

```
y = DataFrame(x)
```

and retrieve the column via y but no luck. However, the command x.columns works. Just can't figure what is the problem here.

Please help!!

Comment: What is `print (x.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Maybe some whitespace like `' col1'` or different separator

Comment: I checked in the csv file. The column names are trimmed(no unwanted spaces).

Comment: Is possible send me your file to my email in my profile if no confidental data?

Comment: I have emailed the file.

Comment: I think I get it, please check my edired answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `read_table` have default separator tab, so is necessary define separator parameter:

```
x = pd.read_table('path to csv', sep=',')
```

Or use `read_csv` with default separator `,`, so `sep`: can be omit.

```
x = pd.read_csv('path to csv')
```

Comment: 'x = pd.read_table('path to csv', sep=',')' Worked! I was not providing `sep=','` earlier. Damn! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to strip the potential whitespaces around the column name with this:

```
x.columns = [col.strip() for col in x.columns.tolist()]
```

Or as suggested in the documenation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) and highlighted in @jezrael's answer:

```
x.columns = x.columns.str.strip()
```

Then, you will be able to access columns with `x.col1..x.coln`. Also be aware that column names are case sensitive.

#### Example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=[' col1', 'col2 '])
>>> df
    col1  col2 
0      1      2
1      3      4
>>> df.col1
Traceback (most recent call last):
..    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col1'
>>> df.col2 
Traceback (most recent call last):
...    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col2'
>>> df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns.tolist()]
>>> df.col1
0    1
1    3
Name: col1, dtype: int64
>>> df.col2 
0    2
1    4
Name: col2, dtype: int64
>>>
```

Comment: I tried 
`df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=[' col1', 'col2 '])
 df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns.tolist()]
df.col1`

Same error.

Comment: @VashisthPatel please share a snippet of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and have checked all the answers (including the first answer), but none work for me, until I ran

```
 print(dataset.columns.tolist())
```

then I found the devil:

```
['\xef\xbb\xbfLabel', 'blabla','blabla']
```

Notice the first element of the row, it should be 'Label' (by the way, it seems Pandas do not welcome 'Label' as your name of label, so I changed to something else later.)

I did a little digging, and found

> the \x actually means that the value is hexadecimal, which is a Byte Order Mark, indicating that the text is Unicode.
>
> Why does it matter to us?
>   You cannot assume the files you read are clean. They might contain extra symbols like this that can throw your scripts off.

in [this article](https://realpython.com/working-with-large-excel-files-in-pandas/)

And I tried many ways to get rid of it, and, the most convenient way is... to add an empty ',' before the first column ( I am using csv, that is to add an empty column before the first column in your dataset for the junk only). Thus, the columns turns out to be:

```
['\xef\xbb\xbf', 'Label', 'blabla', 'blabla']
```

Problem solved!